# Launch wrapped exe with NSIS installer on windows startup

Tags: nsis

I am creating an installer that is wrapping an abc.exe with it. This installer is running the exe as a tray icon. But when I restart my system this exe will stop and won't be seen in tray icon anymore. I want this exe to be started again on windows restart. How can this be achieved?
I have tried below commands but not helpful:

CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS${abc}.lnk" "$INSTDIR\abc.exe"

CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\abc"

CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\abc\abc.lnk" "$INSTDIR\abc.exe"

CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\abc.lnk" "$INSTDIR\abc.exe"

CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\abc\Uninstall abc.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"

Any help is appreciated!!!Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not know that the application is always supposed to run, you need to register it in the correct location.

```
CreateShortcut "$SMSTARTUP\MyApp.lnk" "$INSTDIR\abc.exe"
```

Comment: Anders, I tried your answer and still I don't see abc app on startup. Do I need to make some other changes too?

Comment: I noticed that shortcut is created in the startup folder but it's not getting executed.

Comment: Does your app require UAC elevation? You can also check the startup tab in Task manager.

Comment: Yes Anders, UAC elevation is required.

Comment: Windows ignores startup programs that require elevation because it would be annoying to the user to get UAC dialog(s) on startup.